# Рисование сигмоиды

Tags: c++, qt

```
 ui->customPlot->addGraph();
  ui->customPlot->graph(0)->setPen(QPen(Qt::blue)); // line color blue for first graph


  QVector<double> x(250), y(250);
  for (int i=-125, j=0; i<125; i++, j++)
  {
    x[j] = i;
    y[j] = 1.0 / (1 + pow(2.71, -i));
  }


  connect(ui->customPlot->xAxis, SIGNAL(rangeChanged(QCPRange)), ui->customPlot->xAxis2, SLOT(setRange(QCPRange)));
  connect(ui->customPlot->yAxis, SIGNAL(rangeChanged(QCPRange)), ui->customPlot->yAxis2, SLOT(setRange(QCPRange)));

  ui->customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, y);

  ui->customPlot->graph(0)->rescaleAxes();

  ui->customPlot->setInteractions(QCP::iRangeDrag | QCP::iRangeZoom | QCP::iSelectPlottables);
```

[image: Моя сигмоида]
[image: Каноничная сигмоида]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Может нужно просто поделить `i` на какое-нибудь число, чтобы увеличить горизонтальный масштаб? Скажем, y[j] = `1.0 / (1 + pow(2.71, -i / 15.));`

Comment: Не масштабируете :)